# how does hash slot work in StackExchange.Redis and redis cluster?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

In a 6 nodes cluster with 3 master nodes and 3 replicas.

(you can find more detail on 18 minutes in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NymIgA7Wa78&t=81s))

Every node in a Redis Cluster is responsible for a subset of the hash slots, so for example

```
  Node A contains hash slots from 0 to 5500.
  Node B contains hash slots from 5501 to 11000.
  Node C contains hash slots from 11001 to 16383.
```

So far so good but when trying to get connected to redis cluster and get a value from a key the first request goes to cluster it responses back with which node has the requested hash slot and in the second run the value is get from the key in the calculated hash slot

[image]

so here we have a latency (you can find more detail on 18 minutes in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NymIgA7Wa78&t=81s)) . but if i could use in memory cache for the nodes and hash slot there wont be this round trip.

but i don't know how StackExchange.Redis works

- does StackExchange.Redis internally cache the nodes and hash slots?
- do i have to write this part myself? i can't find any api on S.re to find the node after first call.
- should i calculated hashslot and directly connect to the node
  containing the key for optimization?
- how to connect to redis cluster? should all 6 nodes be presented is multiplexer?

  ```
  var conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("master1,master2,master3,replica1,replica2,replica3,allowAdmin=true");
  ```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140815/using-stackexchange-redis-client-with-redis-cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the hash slot yourself using a standard CRC16 implementation according to CCITT standards. Here is a C# example:

```
public class Checksum
{
    /*
     * Copyright 2001-2010 Georges Menie (www.menie.org)
     * Copyright 2010 Salvatore Sanfilippo (adapted to Redis coding style)
     * All rights reserved.
     * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
     * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
     *
     *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
     *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
     *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
     *       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
     *       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
     *     * Neither the name of the University of California, Berkeley nor the
     *       names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
     *       derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
     *
     * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND ANY
     * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
     * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
     * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
     * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
     * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
     * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
     * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
     * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
     * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
     */

    /* CRC16 implementation according to CCITT standards.
     *
     * Note by @antirez: this is actually the XMODEM CRC 16 algorithm, using the
     * following parameters:
     *
     * Name                       : "XMODEM", also known as "ZMODEM", "CRC-16/ACORN"
     * Width                      : 16 bit
     * Poly                       : 1021 (That is actually x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + 1)
     * Initialization             : 0000
     * Reflect Input byte         : False
     * Reflect Output CRC         : False
     * Xor constant to output CRC : 0000
     * Output for "123456789"     : 31C3
     */

    private static ushort [] crc16tab =
    {
        0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
        0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef,
        0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52b5, 0x4294, 0x72f7, 0x62d6,
        0x9339, 0x8318, 0xb37b, 0xa35a, 0xd3bd, 0xc39c, 0xf3ff, 0xe3de,
        0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64e6, 0x74c7, 0x44a4, 0x5485,
        0xa56a, 0xb54b, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xe5ee, 0xf5cf, 0xc5ac, 0xd58d,
        0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76d7, 0x66f6, 0x5695, 0x46b4,
        0xb75b, 0xa77a, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xf7df, 0xe7fe, 0xd79d, 0xc7bc,
        0x48c4, 0x58e5, 0x6886, 0x78a7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
        0xc9cc, 0xd9ed, 0xe98e, 0xf9af, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xa90a, 0xb92b,
        0x5af5, 0x4ad4, 0x7ab7, 0x6a96, 0x1a71, 0x0a50, 0x3a33, 0x2a12,
        0xdbfd, 0xcbdc, 0xfbbf, 0xeb9e, 0x9b79, 0x8b58, 0xbb3b, 0xab1a,
        0x6ca6, 0x7c87, 0x4ce4, 0x5cc5, 0x2c22, 0x3c03, 0x0c60, 0x1c41,
        0xedae, 0xfd8f, 0xcdec, 0xddcd, 0xad2a, 0xbd0b, 0x8d68, 0x9d49,
        0x7e97, 0x6eb6, 0x5ed5, 0x4ef4, 0x3e13, 0x2e32, 0x1e51, 0x0e70,
        0xff9f, 0xefbe, 0xdfdd, 0xcffc, 0xbf1b, 0xaf3a, 0x9f59, 0x8f78,
        0x9188, 0x81a9, 0xb1ca, 0xa1eb, 0xd10c, 0xc12d, 0xf14e, 0xe16f,
        0x1080, 0x00a1, 0x30c2, 0x20e3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
        0x83b9, 0x9398, 0xa3fb, 0xb3da, 0xc33d, 0xd31c, 0xe37f, 0xf35e,
        0x02b1, 0x1290, 0x22f3, 0x32d2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
        0xb5ea, 0xa5cb, 0x95a8, 0x8589, 0xf56e, 0xe54f, 0xd52c, 0xc50d,
        0x34e2, 0x24c3, 0x14a0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
        0xa7db, 0xb7fa, 0x8799, 0x97b8, 0xe75f, 0xf77e, 0xc71d, 0xd73c,
        0x26d3, 0x36f2, 0x0691, 0x16b0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
        0xd94c, 0xc96d, 0xf90e, 0xe92f, 0x99c8, 0x89e9, 0xb98a, 0xa9ab,
        0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18c0, 0x08e1, 0x3882, 0x28a3,
        0xcb7d, 0xdb5c, 0xeb3f, 0xfb1e, 0x8bf9, 0x9bd8, 0xabbb, 0xbb9a,
        0x4a75, 0x5a54, 0x6a37, 0x7a16, 0x0af1, 0x1ad0, 0x2ab3, 0x3a92,
        0xfd2e, 0xed0f, 0xdd6c, 0xcd4d, 0xbdaa, 0xad8b, 0x9de8, 0x8dc9,
        0x7c26, 0x6c07, 0x5c64, 0x4c45, 0x3ca2, 0x2c83, 0x1ce0, 0x0cc1,
        0xef1f, 0xff3e, 0xcf5d, 0xdf7c, 0xaf9b, 0xbfba, 0x8fd9, 0x9ff8,
        0x6e17, 0x7e36, 0x4e55, 0x5e74, 0x2e93, 0x3eb2, 0x0ed1, 0x1ef0
    };

    public static ushort Compute(byte[] bytes)
    {
        int counter;
        ushort crc = 0;
        for (counter = 0; counter < bytes.Length; counter++)
            crc = (ushort) ((crc << 8) ^ crc16tab[((crc >> 8) ^ bytes[counter]) & 0x00FF]);
        return crc;
    }

    public byte[] ComputeBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        ushort crc = Compute(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }
}
```